# Get element ID in vertex shader in OpenGL

Tags: opengl, vertex-shader

I'm rendering a line that is composed of triangles in OpenGL.

Right now I have it working where:

Vertex buffer: `{v0, v1, v2, v3}`

Index buffer (triangle strip): `{0, 1, 2, 3}`

[image]

The top image is the raw data passed into the vertex shader and the bottom is the vertex shader output after applying an offset to v1 and v3 (using a vertex attribute).

My goal is to use one vertex per point on the line and generate the offset some other way. I was looking at gl_VertexID, but I want something more like an element ID. Here's my desired setup:

Vertex buffer: `{v0, v2}`

Index buffer (triangle strip): `{0, 0, 1, 1}`

and use an imaginary `gl_ElementID % 2` to offset every other vertex.

I'm trying to avoid using geometry shaders or additional vertex attributes. Is there any way of doing this? I'm open to completely different ideas.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can think of one way to avoid the geometry shader and still work with a compact representation: [instanced rendering](https://www.opengl.org/wiki/Vertex_Rendering#Instancing). Just draw many instances of one quad (as a triangle strip), and define the two positions as per-instance attributes via [glVertexAttribDivisor()](https://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man3/xhtml/glVertexAttribDivisor.xml).

Note that you don't need a "template quad" with 4 vertices at all. You just need conceptually two attributes, one for your start point, and one for your end point. (If you work in 2D, you can fuse that into one `vec4`, of course). In each vertex shader invocation, you will have access to both points, and can construct the final vertex position based on that and the value of `gl_VertexID` (which will only be in range 0 to 3). That way, you can get away with exactly that vertex array layout of two points per line segment you are aiming for, and still only need a single draw call and a vertex shader.

Comment: Cool idea! I tried it out and it works well. To summarize, my vertex buffer is now `{v0, v1, v2, ..., vN}` and index buffer is simply  `{0, 1, 2, 3}`. I have two vertex attributes: position and nextPosition (using a pointer offset), give both `glVertexAttribDivisor([0/1], 1)`, and call `glDrawElementsInstanced(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 4, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, 0, N-1)`. The vertex shader selects between position and nextPosition based on `gl_VertexID <= 1` and applies the line offset based on `gl_VertexID % 2`.

Comment: Nice to hear it's working well. Although the question still remains whether this approach is more or less efficient than just using the GS. It might be, but I'm not sure.

Comment: Also, this approach streams more indices than my original implementation (4N vs 2N), but it's pretty difficult to determine the true cost without profiling.

Comment: Instancing one line segment just doesn't seem right. I don't know the context, but there has to be atleast one nicer solution.

Comment: @Petwoip If the index buffer is simply `{0, 1, 2, 3}`, then there is no point in using an index buffer? The same thing can be accomplished with `glDrawArraysInstanced`.

Answer (score 1):

No, that is not possible, because each vertex is only processed once. So if you're referencing a vertex 10 times with an index buffer, the corresponding vertex shader is still only executed one time.

This is implemented in hardware with the [Post Transform Cache](https://www.opengl.org/wiki/Post_Transform_Cache).

> In the absolute best case, you never have to process the same vertex
>   more than once.
>
> The test for whether a vertex is the same as a previous one is
>   somewhat indirect. It would be impractical to test all of the
>   user-defined attributes for inequality. So instead, a different means
>   is used.
>
> Two vertices are considered equal (within a single rendering command)
>   if the vertex's index and instance count are the same (gl_VertexID​
>   and gl_InstanceID​ in the shader). Since vertices for non-indexed
>   rendering are always increasing, it is not possible to use the post
>   transform cache with non-indexed rendering.
>
> If the vertex is in the post transform cache, then that vertex data is
>   not necessarily even read from the input vertex arrays again. The
>   process skips the read and vertex shader execution steps, and simply
>   adds another copy of that vertex's post-transform data to the output
>   stream.

To solve your problem I would use a geometry shader with a line (or line strip) as input and a triangle strip as output. With this setup you could get rid of the index buffer, since it's only working on lines.